# SonarQube background tasks failing with NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

Project analysis on the build server succeeds, but the background task on the SonarQube server fails with NoNodeAvailableException

```
2016.03.09 19:25:43 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVNcfU8up676eFKtj1O2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.index(IssueIndexer.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.IndexIssuesStep.execute(IndexIssuesStep.java:38) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.bulk(TransportClient.java:370) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder.doExecute(BulkRequestBuilder.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.executeBulk(BulkIndexer.java:223) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.add(BulkIndexer.java:142) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.doIndex(IssueIndexer.java:86) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.doIndex(IssueIndexer.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.access$000(IssueIndexer.java:34) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer$1.index(IssueIndexer.java:56) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$1.run(BaseIndexer.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2016.03.09 19:25:43 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=mycompany:myproduct | id=AVNcfU8up676eFKtj1O2 | time=2312294ms
```

What is this error and how can I fix it?

And: to my understanding the data gathering on the build server side was complete and it pushed everything to the SonarQube server. Is it possible to trigger the background task again (for the already transmitted data) and see if it can complete this time? This would be really nice because the build server needs 3:30h to complete and the background task failed after 39 min. So it's a bit tedious to simply try the whole thing again.

Comment: You need to check the connection parameters. For "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.0" the connection is defined in SonarQubeAnalysis.xml. The user configured in this file must be an user with Analysis rights. You also can start with a simple -test- application.

Comment: @Jeroen to clarify: I'm setting up a new build server. The SonarQube analysis did already succeed for the past couple of days (it's executed by the nightly build). Then this error happened and now last night it succeeded again without me changing anything.
So I'd like to know what's causing/caused this error so it can be avoided in the future.
Also, it would be really useful to be able to start a failed background task again.

Comment: The background task restart idea is an excellent one. I just had a 3:30 build fail analysis and I'd rather not rerun the whole build.